# is it possible to make an attribute optional when creating an object?

Tags: java

Okay so i have this class

```
public DBRestorerWorker(String dbName, Path fromFile, Path targetDataPath, Path targetLogPath,
        ProgressBar bar, Properties properties, Runnable done) {
    this.dbName = dbName;
    this.targetDataPath = targetDataPath;
    this.from = fromFile;
    this.targetLogPath = targetLogPath;
    this.bar = bar;
    this.properties = properties;
    this.done = done;
}
```

this class is used in an application and now i am creating a slimmed down version of it so i need to still use this part but in the slimmed version there is no ProgressBar but i still need to create an object of this class so is there someway to make the ProgressBar optional since the old version still needs it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a new constructor which simply assigns `null` to the `ProgressBar` field:

```
public DBRestorerWorker(String dbName, Path fromFile, Path targetDataPath,
    Path targetLogPath, Properties properties, Runnable done) {

    DBRestorerWorker(dbName, fromFile, targetDataPath, targetLogPath, null,
        properties, done);
}
```

If you can't modify the original class for some reason, then you can still extend your previous class and add this constructor.

Comment: I've been to slow answering the same thing ;) So +1 to you instead.

Comment: @Julien Funny you should say this, because I was surprised that Eran or Jon Skeet did not beat me to it first.

Comment: Unfortunately this is correct. You add additional constructors as necessary. This gets messy really quickly if you have several optional parameters. I hope Oracle fits in default values in Java 11.

Comment: Du you guys have a full time job on SO ? :D

Comment: @dit My job bores me, so I come to this site for refreshment.  Sort of like the wardrobe, in the book the Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen time to change a job I would say :P

Answer (score 2):

[Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is your fried.

```
public final class DBRestorerWorker {

    private final String dbName;
    private final Path fromFile;
    private final Path targetDataPath;
    private final Path targetLogPath;
    private final ProgressBar bar;
    private final Properties properties;
    private final Runnable done;

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    private DBRestorerWorker(Builder builder) {
        this.dbName = builder.dbName;
        // same for others
    }

    // getters

    public static final class Builder {
        private String dbName;
        private Path fromFile;
        private Path targetDataPath;
        private Path targetLogPath;
        private ProgressBar bar;
        private Properties properties;
        private Runnable done;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public Builder dbName(String dbName) {
            this.dbName = dbName;
            return this;
        }

        // same for other fields

        public DBRestorerWorker build() {
            return new DBRestorerWorker(this);
        }

    }
}
```

Using is like this:

```
DBRestorerWorker worker = DBRestorerWorker.builder()
                                          .dbName("dbName")
                                          // other required fields
                                          .build();
```

**P.S.** [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) could simplify this pattern usage.

Comment: I like this approach, and would consider adding in a bit of the Null Object pattern to come up with a NullProgressBar since passing null into a constructor seems uggo. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern#Java

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can simply pass in `null`. Optionally and additionally mark the parameter as `@Nullable`. Maybe create a second constructor without the ProgressBar which calls this constructor with a `null`.

```
public DBRestorerWorker(String dbName, Path fromFile, Path targetDataPath, Path targetLogPath, Properties properties, Runnable done) {
    DBRestorerWorker(dbName, fromFile, targetDataPath, targetLogPath, null, properties, done)
}
```

and optionally the `@Nullable`:

```
public DBRestorerWorker(String dbName, Path fromFile, Path targetDataPath, Path targetLogPath, @Nullable ProgressBar bar, Properties properties, Runnable done) {
    // ...
}
```